# Mounting/Unmounting USB disks on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, usb

On Windows Server, by default, external USB disks don't always get mounted. I'd like my program (written in C#) to be able to detect external USB disks, identify them, and then mount them.

When it's finished, it should do whatever the programmatic equivalent of "Safely Remove Hardware" in order to flush and unmount the disk.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the functions [SetVolumeMountPointA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setvolumemountpointa) and [DeleteVolumeMountPointW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletevolumemountpointw).

In order to find Volumes you could use [FindFirstVolumeW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstvolumew) and [FindNextVolumeW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextvolumew).